# Firebase Cloud Function Data cannot be encoded BigInt

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript, google-cloud-functions

I am specifically working with the Square API where they regularly use the bigint type. Is there an easy way to encode this bigint as a String?

Error:

```
Data cannot be encoded in JSON. 1634864610834n
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check for `BigInt` and convert to/from a string by passing a closure as the second argument to the `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` methods.  Here's a great article with more info.

https://golb.hplar.ch/2018/09/javascript-bigint.html#json